# mysql select closest result from todays date past/future

Tags: mysql

I am sure this is a common task although all of the examples I have looked at dont help me solve this issue.

I have 2 tables:

> 1. `events`
> 2. `schedules` with foreign key to events. With `schedule_datetime_from` and `schedule_datetime_until`

Q. When selecting all of the events, how would I also fetch/join the first closest schedule based on todays date? E.g only return the most relevant schedule.

NOTE: There maybe more than one schedule for each event. The schedule may also be in the past.

E.g `e.schedule_datetime_from >= NOW() OR schedule_datetime_until > NOW()` would return only the future schedules, but how do I also return schedules in the past. Or do I need to use a ORDER BY + LIMIT 1 to achieve this?

Comment: can you elaborate more on this `closest schedule based on the date`? by how many days?

Comment: Infinite amount of days, just returning the most relevant schedule from today. The complex bit is this could be past/future

Comment: Sorry I mean `closest schedule based on todays date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select e.*, s.*
from 
    events e
    inner join 
    schedules s on e.id = s.event_id
order by 
    abs(unix_timestamp(schedule_datetime_from) - unix_timestamp(now())))
limit 1
```

Comment: Please explain why this is a good answer, don't just throw out code.

Comment: @theTinMan The `abs` function, obviously I guess, makes the past and future schedules to be compared just on the distance from `now`.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE DATE(date_column)
BETWEEN DATE(CURDATE()) AND DATE(CURDATE()+7);

This will give you a weeks heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to select a group of events between dates you can use

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE date BETWEEN 'mm-dd-yyyy' AND 'mm-dd-yyyy'
```

If you want to select the most recent date you can add

```
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Not looking for a condition for the dates, this could be infinite. How about if there is a schedule 10 years in advanced and there is another schedule set for tomorrow?

Comment: I see, so you want to know the closest event to today, past or future?

Comment: Yes I guess this would be a JOIN with an ORDER BY IF(future OR past)

Comment: Then what I would do is get the closest event before and after, and find the minimum difference.

Comment: use `DATEDIFF(future, NOW())` and `DATEDIFF(past, NOW())` and get the `MIN()`